# What is the connection String to connect to the SQL Server database in web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-config

What is the connection string in `web.config` to connect to a SQL Server database using ASP.NET ?

[image]

Comment: check out this:https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it in node `<connectionStrings></<connectionStrings>>`
Example:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add 
    name="NorthwindConnectionString" 
    connectionString="Data Source=serverName;Initial 
    Catalog=Northwind;Persist Security Info=True;User 
    ID=userName;Password=password"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
  />
</connectionStrings>
```

And how to read it in code:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig =
                System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/MyWebSiteRoot");
            System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings connString;
            if (rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Count > 0)
            {
                connString =
                    rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["NorthwindConnectionString"];
                if (connString != null)
                    Console.WriteLine("Northwind connection string = \"{0}\"",
                        connString.ConnectionString);
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("No Northwind connection string");
            }
```

> Update: You need to specify the connection name in your DbContext

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public YourDbContext() 
        : base("YourConnectionName") 
    { 
    } 
}
```

And your web config:

```
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="YourConnectionName"
        connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|DatabaseName.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I want a connection string for web.config to connect to DB_ALThez.mdf . See the image above.Without servername,pass.user

Comment: The ConnectionStrings element will only exist if you used individual user accounts, it will not exist if you used no authentication.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You need to create new connection and specify it in your DbContext

Answer (score 0):

Demo

```
<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;database=myDb;uid=myUser;password=myPass;" />
```

Comment: Thank you. But I want a connection string for web.config to connect to DB_ALThez.mdf . See the image above.Without servername,pass.user